# How to write a script to analyse C# code using FxCop?

Tags: c#, hudson, analysis, fxcop

I am trying to write a script to analyse C# code (batch script) using FxCop and integrate scripts into Hudson to automate the task. Can anyone can help? Even help to get me halfway is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few hints to get you started:

- Write a batch script that executes [FxCopCmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429474%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the command-line tool for FxCop.
- Use the [Violations](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Violations) plugin to display the analysis results in Hudson.

I also suggest that you use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) instead of Hudson, but this is not necessary.